# I have uploaded some mp3 files in server folder. How can i load these mp3 files in my android App?

Tags: android, android-studio, mp3

I am developing a Android app for a online music player site. I want to load mp3 files from my server to my Android App using URL.. Please somebody help ?

Comment: show your code what have you tried

Answer (score 0):

There are two options,
1) Stream directly from url
2) Download the file from url to your storage(internal/external) and then play

Answer (score 0):

i hope this link will help you better [MP3 Streaming by URL](https://www.hrupin.com/2011/02/example-of-streaming-mp3-mediafile-with-android-mediaplayer-class)